# Email input in Magento Product

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, product

I need to add this 3 custom attributes to a Magento product:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Contact

I need it to be in the product page so that the user can add the information. I can't use and don't want to use the billing information. From what I understand that all attributes are configured and filled via back-end and not in front-end.

Imagine for example poster and I want to print this fields on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution is to develop a custom attribute that presents in self in a way of a form in the product view.

Then we need to catch the inputs on does forms and then do whatever we need to do with this data.

There is no simple implementation in one of magento versions and also there is no extension free or paid in the market. This need to be done from scratch.